# Difference between the next row and the current row pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, automation, timestamp

I am working on an automation task wherein the column 'Duration' should contain the time difference of the column named 'Timestamp' of its next row and its respective row in seconds for all rows except the last one.

The last row of column 'Duration' should contain zero.

I have got a dataset of around 71,979 rows is there a generalized function which we can apply.

```
Timestamp              Duration
4/30/2020 21:27         1819
4/30/2020 21:57         1816
4/30/2020 22:27         1821
4/30/2020 22:58         1821
4/30/2020 23:28         1814
4/30/2020 23:58           0
```

Comment: `df['Duration'] = df.Timestamp.diff()`?

Comment: `(df['Timestamp'].diff() / np.timedelta64(1,'s')).bfill()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['Duration'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], errors='coerce').diff(-1).dt.total_seconds()
```